# ¿ cannot convert 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'char'?

Tags: c++

tengo este error al intentar ingresar valores a un `std::vector` de tipo `struct` en c++ pero no entiendo el error, he consultado previamente en otros foros y generalmente es porque intentar meter un `const char *` a un método que pide `std::string` y les recomiendan usar la función `c_str()`, pero en mi caso no entiendo la razón porque el compilador me dice que no meta un `std::string` en un espacio que me esta pidiendo `char` cuando lo que debería pedir es un `std::string`, anexo mi código

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "componentes.h"

void IPs_llenar(std::vector<information>& info){    
    std::string IP;
   
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) info.capacity(); i++){                
        unsigned int octet1 = (rand() % 255);
        unsigned int octet2 = (rand() % 255);
        unsigned int octet3 = (rand() % 255);
        unsigned int octet4 = (rand() % 255);
        
        std::cout<<"[IPs] 4 rands creates:"<<'\n';

        IP = std::to_string(octet1) + "." + 
             std::to_string(octet2) + "." + 
             std::to_string(octet3) + "." +
             std::to_string(octet4);

        info[i].IPs.push_back(IP);       
     }
 }
```

aqui esta el error cuando me refiero a que la estructura solo tiene `std::string` y no tiene ningun `char` que le pueda pasar.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

struct information{
  std::string IPs;
  std::string IPd;
  std::string IPm;
  std::string IPb; 
  
  std::string IPc;
  uint32_t IPn;
}; 

struct database{    
  uint32_t lrange;  
  uint32_t urange;   
  std::string country;    
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

El error se produce porque, si miramos la documentación de [`std::string< >::push_back( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back), esta función-miembro espera **un `char`** como argumento, y tu estás intentando pasarle un `std::string< >`. Y el compilador *se queja* al no encontrar la forma de convertir una `std::string< >` a un `char` que es lo esperado.

No queda claro que es lo que pretendes hacer con esa llamada a `push_back( )`.

- Para asignar, lo puedes hacer directamente:

  `info[i].IPs = IP;`
- Para concatenar, también:

  ```
  info[i].IPs += ',';
  info[i].IPS += IP;
  ```

Comment: @jose el operador `push_back` es para agregar un solo caracter al final. Tanto [`append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) como [`+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) tienen sobrecargas para agregar una cadena de caracteres al final. Sugiero que mires la documentación para ver todos los usos que tiene.